# How store user from this.$auth.fetchUser()?

Tags: nuxtjs

I have a Nuxtjs app which authenticates fine. But I need the user details for filling out a form automatically. I see that the app calls /user endpoint on every reload. I want to insert a $store in its callback to store the user data in $store.

```
computed: {
    getUser () {
      return this.$store.state.user.user;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setUser (data) {
      this.$store.commit('user/add', data)
    },
}
```

NUXT Config:

```
auth: {
strategies: {
    local: {
        endpoints: {
            login: {
                url: '/auth/login',
                method: 'post',
                propertyName: 'access_token'
            },
            logout: {
                url: '/auth/logout',
                method: 'post'
            },
            user: {
                url: '/auth/user',
                method: 'get',
                propertyName: false
            },
            tokenRequired: true
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is it possible to intercept the $auth.fetchUser or whatever method $auth is using to fetch the api/user endpoint on every reload?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using auth and vuex methods. I don't need to intercept the call. Just use

```
this.$auth.user
```

or

```
this.$store.state.auth.user;
```

Learning Nuxt/Vuejs is fun.